# USB devices changes ttyACM and device rumber on automatic reconnect

Tags: pi-4, usb, serial

I have a Quark elec AIS receiver connected to my raspberry pi 4 and after some randon amount of time it disconnects en reconnects. After this the device number and the ttyACM* number changes. See the log of dmesg below:

```
[81474.515734] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[81474.757311] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[81474.871135] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5785, bcdDevice= 2.00
[81474.871150] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[81474.871156] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Composity
[81474.871161] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: GD32
[81474.871165] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 200000022405
[81474.879037] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
```

After this AIS dispatcher stops receiving data because its connected to ttyACM0 but this doesn't exist. My question is: Is there a way to force this device to a port so even on a reconnect it stays on this port.